# Windows phone textbox input as an octal number

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox

Can i capture the textbox input as an octal number in windows phone 7 ?

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to check if string is octal? Covert it to octal integer? What language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can covert string to int use:

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32("010", 8);
```

if it throws `FormatException` then number cannot be converted.

Comment: Thanks.Corrent.That's what i wanted