# Validate octal number

Tags: c#, validation, octal

Is this a valid way to validate if a string contains only octal numbers?

```
public static bool IsOctal(String toCheck)
{
    if (toCheck.Contains(" "))
    {
        return false;
    }
    int parsedtoCheck;
    var parseOk = int.TryParse(toCheck, out parsedtoCheck);
    if (!parseOk)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (Convert.ToInt32(toCheck, 8) != parsedtoCheck)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: According to [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377655/windows-phone-textbox-input-as-an-octal-number) it looks like you may have an answer already (not that I advocate throwing exceptions as a test for conversion)

Comment: @jeffdot: the expection should never be thrown, because the toCheck is a valid integer after the TryParse, or did i miss anything?

Comment: Perhaps: `try{Convert.ToInt32(toCheck, 8);return true;}catch{return false}`

Comment: @benba: No, because "9" will succeed in `int.TryParse` but not in `Convert.ToInt32(toCheck, 8)`. And other values (e.g. "10") which *should* succeed will return `false`, because octal 10 isn't equal to decimal 10...

Comment: @JonSkeet: The first point i got, overread them in the documentation. But the second one, Convert.ToInt32(10, 8) returns an Int32 10 and compared to another 10 it should be the same? I thought C# don't know any representation for octals?

Comment: @benba: What do you think `Convert.ToInt32("10", 8)` does? It's not a matter of *C#* knowing about octal - it's a matter of `Convert.ToInt32(string, int)` knowing about it. `Convert.ToInt32("10", 8)` will return 8, because that's the value of "10" interpreted as an octal value.

Comment: it seems to be time for bed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not at all clear what your current approach is trying to achieve, as it's converting in both decimal and octal. If you just want to check whether the string only contains digits 0-7, it's probably simplest to use a regex:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Do you want this to be valid or not?
        Console.WriteLine(IsOctal(""));
        Console.WriteLine(IsOctal("012"));
        Console.WriteLine(IsOctal("890"));
        Console.WriteLine(IsOctal("abc"));
        // Do you want this to be valid or not?
        Console.WriteLine(IsOctal("-0123"));
    }

    private static bool IsOctal(string text)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(text, "^[0-7]+$");
    }
}
```

This assumes that:

- You're only interested in non-negative values (so we don't need to accept a leading `-`)
- An empty string should not be deemed valid
- You don't need the actual *value* afterwards - it can be as long as you like

Comment: And I would have thought you would go with a linq approach.

Comment: @gunr2171: While that's always an option I think of, in this case I think it would be less readable than the regex.

Comment: Or even "012".All(x => x>='0' && x<'8')

Answer (score 2):

If performance is important, you may want to benchmark the regex solution vs. a scan (adapted from [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/223854/55487)):

```
private bool IsOctal(IEnumerable<char> chars)
{
    bool isOctal;
    foreach (var c in chars)
    {
        isOctal = (c >= '0' && c <= '7');

        if (!isOctal)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And as earlier answers pointed out, this makes some assumptions about your numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

This highly depends on your validation rules. There's no one true definition of an octal number's character set. Sometimes starting with 0 is mandatory. In Python I believe you can use _ as a digit separator. Negatives? Scientific/engineering notation? Decimals?

Yes, some of those are odd, but the point is, this depends on where you're using it.

Do you need it to be parseable in C#? Then int.TryParse() is the way to go. You just parsed it and got a success or failure. Does it need to be passed as a string to another service/API? Look up that service/API's validation rules. Also don't double-check like you're doing above, it's just confusing what the real valid set of characters is, and if you don't trust your runtime you might as well start building one you do trust (don't do this, that was a joke).

Find out what the real validation rules and requirements are, and your answer will be clear. Don't overthink it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a linq solution:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = IsOctal("023"); //true
    var b = IsOctal("678"); //false
}

public static bool IsOctal(string text)
{
    //get a collection of chars that each text element can be
    var possibleChars = Enumerable.Range(0, 8)
        .Select(x => x.ToString()[0]);

    //"are there any chars in 'text' that are not in 'possibleChar'?"
    var anyAreInvalid = text
        .Where(x => !possibleChars.Contains(x))
        .Any();

    //return the inverse of your question
    return !anyAreInvalid;
}
```

The main work is in the `Where` statement, which checks each character in your input against an "acceptable chars" list.

This also takes the same assumptions from [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25295485).